# Singletons only available once in Scala

Tags: scala, macros, singleton

Often we need objects that can be reused and takes some time to generate:

```
def foo() = {
  // long lines of code...
  val pattern = Pattern.comile("pattern") // suppose this takes long time
  // use pattern
}
```

Then it can be moved to outer scope

```
private[this] lazy val pattern = Pattern.comile("pattern") // suppose this takes long time

def foo() = {
  // long lines of code...
  // pattern need to be available only here!
  // use pattern
}
```

But this complicates the source because it leaks scope of the variable `pattern`, while it is used only in specific location of `foo`. I am curious about this can be simplified with a macro function:

```
def foo() = {
  // long lines of code...
  val pattern = singleton { Pattern.comile("pattern") }
  // use pattern
}
```

If it is possible, we can extend it for more interesting case; `ThreadLocal` singleton:

```
def foo() = {
  // long lines of code...
  val obj = threadLocal { new NotThreadSafeObject() }
  // use obj
}
```

Which will be extended as:

```
private[this] lazy val foo_obj_gen_by_macro = {
  val tl = new ThreadLocal[NotThreadSafeObject]()
  tl.set(new NotThreadSafeObject())
  tl
}
def foo() = {
  // long lines of code...
  val obj = foo_obj_gen_by_macro.get
  // use obj
}
```

If it would C++, this can be very easily achieved by using `static` variable inside of function scope:

```
void foo() {
    // long lines of code...
    static Pattern pattern = Pattern.Compile("pattern");
    // use pattern
}
```

Comment: A macro annotation can rewrite a class to move the computation into the companion. It would be nice if it were doable with def macro; regex compilation is a use case of interest. This issue was raised again recently.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just scope it ?

```
  lazy val foo: () => String = {
    val pattern = Pattern.compile("pattern")

    def result(): String = ???

    result _
  }
```

Or as [thoredge mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33604299/singletons-only-available-once-in-scala/33604565?noredirect=1#comment54985010_33604565) even simpler

```
lazy val foo: () => String = {
    val pattern = Pattern.compile("pattern")

    () => ???
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, but your suggestion is not simple as much as I need. For the C++ case, we just need to add `static` keyword.

Comment: The question is in short: "is it possible to write a function `singleton` working as I describe above?"

Comment: The returned function could be shortened down to () => { ??? } making it in my view very simple and usable. I'll use it :-)